# screen sharing stops working

Tags: macos, screen-sharing

Periodically my screen sharing stops working.  When I try to connect nothing happens. 
telnet 5900 connects but I don't get the normal "RFB 003.889" prompt back.
reboot seems to resolve it, but it stops working soon.
I tried killing SCreenSharingAgent and it restarts, but still doesn't work.
Any advice on how to make it work remotely via ssh?

(11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2)

Comment: 11.4.2 relates to which OS X version? Do you have physical access to the computer of which you want to access the screen?

Comment: @patrix sorry, I assumed kernel version maps to OS X version.  It is 10.7.  Yes, I do have physical access.